# Aligning two input elements inside of a <div>

Tags: html, css

This is a rather trivial question, but I cannot figure it out. I have tried to use the property `inline-block`, as well as floating the elements but the two inputs will not go side by side. Here is a [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jysLe7v1/)

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 2em;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
outline: none;
}

.bookmarkInputs {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 100px;     
}

.test {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div class='bookmarkInputs'>
        <input id='addNameInput' class='test' type='text'>
        <input id='addURLinput' class='test' type='text'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `input` tag's width at 50% or less

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` is 100% width, so both your `input` will try to fit the `.bookmarkInputs`. Just make its width smaller.

```css
input {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    width: 48%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 2em;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.bookmarkInputs {
    width: 250px
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 100px;     
}

.test {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div class='bookmarkInputs'>
        <input id='addNameInput' class='test' type='text'>
        <input id='addURLinput' class='test' type='text'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your input has 100%, you must modify it and place it like this

```
input {
 /*width: 100%;*/
  width: 48%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 2em;
```

}